# ReadMoreTextview not working on New Line of text

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, textview

I'm using see more & see less functionality using [this code](https://github.com/ilyapuchka/ReadMoreTextView). But I'm stuck on one condition that is if I've content with \n or new line text then it's not working as I expected.

[image]

If I tap see less off text then it's expanding to full text. But not in exact See Less text.

Comment: Gautam Sareriya, any solution?

Comment: @BhavinChauhan Use this one instead of that https://github.com/ilyapuchka/ReadMoreTextView

Comment: Both are same, please check your above comment

Comment: Any solution? @GautamSareriya

Comment: Please inform me if you guys have any solution.